# >Hieararchy nodes in OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm working with OSMnx and Networkx to solve the Vehicle Routing Problem. In the solution that I'm trying to implement I need that some nodes with lower hierarchy connect directly with the ones with higher hierarchy, but, this would be easier if OSMnx have an option to do it. Anyone know if this is possible with OSMnx?

Thanks

**EDIT**

With OSMnx I load the graph and the road nodes with differents hierarchy in this way:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place({'city':'Medellín', 'state':'Antioquia'},network_type='drive', buffer_dist=60000,
                                infrastructure='way["highway"]',
                                custom_filter='["highway"~"motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential"]')
```

Where the custom_filter gives me the hierarchy of the road.  Suppose that I have a position and calculate the nearest node to that position like this:

```
orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, c_ori,method='haversine') #c_ori = position
```

Turns out that orig_node is in a road with lower hierarchy (residential and unclassified).  I need to know if OSMnx have a way to connect directly that node with the closest node with a higher hierarchy(trunk, primary, etc)?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any code example? Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, would help you and us.

Comment: @dboy Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMnx does not have a built-in ability to search only for roads at a certain level of the hierarchy. But you can do this by simply making a second graph for searching only the road types you want:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

# graph of all the streets you want to model
place = {'city': 'Medellín', 'state': 'Antioquia'}
cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link|primary|secondary|tertiary|unclassified|residential"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', buffer_dist=60000, custom_filter=cf)

# graph of only the streets you want to search
cf_search = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link"]'
G_search = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', buffer_dist=60000, custom_filter=cf_search)

print(len(G)) #40341
print(len(G_search)) #4562

# find a node in the road types you want to search
point = -75.54838, 6.22752
orig = ox.get_nearest_node(G_search, point, method='haversine')
dest = list(G)[0]

# impute edge speeds, add travel times, solve shortest path
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)
route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight='travel_time')
len(route) #141
```